# In ecto migration is there a way to rename a table without updating the constraint references

Tags: elixir, ecto

I'm trying to change a non null column to a column that can be null.

```
alter table(:members) do
  modify :email, :string, null: true
end
```

However as I'm using sqlite I'm getting: `ALTER COLUMN not supported by SQLite3`

I attempted to rename the table and copy the data to a new table. However renaming the table also updates all the constraint references. The sqlite docs say I should modify some pragmas, however I can not work out how to do that in an ecto migration.

```
execute "PRAGMA foreign_keys = OFF"
execute "PRAGMA legacy_alter_table = ON"
```

Does not work. How can I do this?

Full migration code:

```
defmodule Oas.Repo.Migrations.NullEmail do
  use Ecto.Migration

  def up do
    # alter table(:members) do
    #   modify :email, :string, null: true
    # end

    execute "PRAGMA foreign_keys=OFF"
    execute "PRAGMA legacy_alter_table = ON"
    result = repo().query! "PRAGMA foreign_keys"
    # This should return 0, it returns 1 :(
    IO.inspect(result)
    
    rename table(:members), to: table(:members_tmp6)

    create table(:members) do
      add :email, :string, null: true, collate: :nocase
      add :name, :string, null: false

      timestamps()
    end
    
    execute("INSERT INTO members SELECT * FROM members_tmp6")

    execute "PRAGMA foreign_keys=ON"
    execute "PRAGMA legacy_alter_table=OFF"

    drop table(:members_tmp6)
  end

  def down do
    
  end
end
```

Comment: this question is related to sqlite3 internals, not elixir and ecto.

Comment: It is related to ecto, as those PRAGMA queries are correct, I just can't execute them in ecto.

Comment: are you executing the statements inside of change or up function?

Comment: Yes, in an up function.

Comment: please show the full migrations code, as there is no way that sql statements are not executed.